# Entity framework generated SQL problem (multiple joins on same table)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

Having a bit of problem understanding why EF (4.1) is generating a particular SQL query. Here goes:

Basically I have these two classes

```
public class Rota
{
    public int RotaId { get; set; }

    public int RotaGroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual RotaGroup RotaGroup { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    ...
```

and

```
public class RotaGroup
{
    public int RotaGroupId { get; private set; }

    public bool IsCurrentRota { get; set; }

    ...
```

The mappings for rota is as follows:

```
HasKey(r => r.RotaId);
Property(r=>r.RotaId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

HasRequired(r => r.RotaGroup).WithMany()
                             .HasForeignKey(r => r.RotaGroupId)
                             .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

HasRequired(r => r.Employee).WithMany()
                            .HasForeignKey(r => r.EmployeeId)
                            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

...

Ok. Now the following linq query:

```
_context.Rotas.Include(r => r.RotaGroup)
              .Where(r => r.EmployeeId == 1 && r.RotaGroup.IsCurrentRota)
              .ToList();
```

Generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT ...columns...
FROM [dbo].[Rota] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[RotaGroup] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[RotaGroupId] = [Extent2][RotaGroupId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[RotaGroup] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[RotaGroupId] = [Extent3].[RotaGroupId] 
WHERE ([Extent2].[IsCurrentRota] = 1) AND ([Extent1].[MyIgluUserId] = 1
```

Im sure you can see the issue. Why oh why is it joining on rotaGroup (as it should) and then doing a left outer join? Further more the columns from [Extent2] (the inner join) are not used. Only the columns from the left outer join bit ([Extent3]) are used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[Extent2]` is used - it is part of SQL's `WHERE`. The result of the query will be correct but the performance will be probably worse. I don't think SQL server will optimize this to get rid of unnecessary left join.

That is how EF generates queries. As I understand it, EF doesn't track usage of entity sets so those two query parts `Include(r => r.RotaGroup)` and `Where(r => r.RotaGroup.IsCurrentRota)` are not related to each other. Left join is result of `Include` and inner join is result of `Where`. You can try to  modify query so that part with `Include` is subquery of filtering but I doubt it will work differently.

Comment: Unfortunately no, SQL is not optimizing the query. So let me get this straight, EF is using the LEFT OUTER JOIN because of the Include, and the INNER JOIN is being used because of the Where? That is awfully strange. Also RotaGroupId is a required foreign key on rota, so why is it using a LEFT OUTER JOIN...

Comment: Maybe it is my fault, you see, the reason I am doing Include(r => r.RotaGroup) is so I can access the IsCurrentRota property of RotaGroup. This allows me to find all rotas where RotaGroup.IsCurrentRota is true, is this the correct way of doing this???

Comment: Simply that is how queries are generated. That is not a problem we can solve here. If you have complains post it as a bug to [connect.microsoft.com](http://connect.microsoft.com/) or as a request for change in [user voice](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions) - I expect there will be already few of them. If you have support tickets you can also request MS support or ask on [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/threads/) for help.

Comment: No that is not a correct way. `Include` is for telling EF that you want rota groups in the result set (eager loading). Accessing navigation properties for filtering is possible without using `Include`.

Comment: Ah yes the include is not necessary. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Running into a similar issue on my end, where multiple JOINs are generated when they are not needed (i.e. the SQL query could easily be altered to include just one INNER JOIN to a parent table instead of having both an INNER and LEFT JOIN to the parent table).

My problem was also about testing for equality to multiple values (e.g. where child.ParentID == 1 || child.ParentID == 2 || child.ParentID == 3), which created a messed up where clause (where tbl1 and tbl2 are the INNER and LEFT joined tables added to the SELECT statement):

WHERE tbl1.ParentID = 1 or tbl2.ParentID IN (2, 3)

Both of these issues have been corrected in the 2011 June CTP package: 
[Entity framework CTP - June 2011](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx)